# perl: what is the right way to call a function stored in a variable?

Tags: perl

What is the right way to call a function stored in a variable?

```
my $f = sub () { ... };
&$f();  # 1st
$f->(); # 2nd
```

Both appear to work, and the first probably worked in `perl4`.

However, I was wondering what the "official `perl5` way" was.

Also, are there any performance implications?

Comment: For me, the second one is waaaay more readable, and somehow I think that should be of the most concern. )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are *the right way*. Perl is not about forcing any special style down your throat.

#### Style #1 `&$f()`

*Pro:*

- Emphasizes that we are using a subroutine

*Con:*

- Looks like line noise
- Overrides function templates
- Seems a bit *perl4*-ly to me

*Caveats:*

In the dark ages of perl4, there were no references. One could simulate references by passing around variable *names* (*shudder*). This also works with subs, so this code runs:

```
sub f { (shift == 0) ? 1 : 0 }
$g = "f";
print &$g(1); # prints 0;
print &$g(0); # prints 1;
```

Please `use strict 'refs'` to guard against this horror.

#### Style #2 `$f->()`

*Pro:*

- Emphasizes that we are handling a reference
- Looks cleaner

*Con:*

- can be confused with objects and hashrefs

*Caveats:*

Same as with the other syntax, as they are the same under the hood. But the dereference operator is not misused as often.

#### Performance implications

Lets face it, if we were all about performance, we would be writing assembler. If you want to optimize Perl, first optimize the algorithm, then code everything in C/XS, throw away any objects and modules, and finally discuss dereferencing syntax.

I would *guess* style #1 is faster in theory, but I doubt it would have serious implications in real life.

Comment: +1. I don't think that line about objects and hashrefs confusion is for real, but otherwise, very good points. )

Comment: I think you should mention what `&$f;` does. `&$f()` is totally surpassed in Perl 5, but `&$f` still does something that neither his examples do.

Answer (score 4):

I sincerely doubt there are any differences performance, since both methods result in the same code:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'&$f()'
&$f();
-e syntax OK
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'$f->()'
&$f();
-e syntax OK
```